# MVC Models, what are they for?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

The time has come for me to understand MVC, so that's what I'm trying to do; and I'm having trouble getting what a model is supposed to do. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), a model:

> The model manages the behaviour and data of the application domain,
>   responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the
>   controller). In event-driven systems, the model notifies observers
>   (usually views) when the information changes so that they can react.

And in CakePHP, you supposedly set up a model in this very simple way:

```
<?php

class Posts extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Posts';
}

?>
```

So if I wanted, for example, the last 10 posts in my database, I would create a controller which would look something like this:

```
<?php

class PostsController {
    function retrieve_latest($number = 10) {
        $posts = $this->Users->find(array(
                'fields' => '*',
                'order' => 'posts.post_id DESC',
                'limit' => $number,
                'page' => '1',
                'conditions' => array('posts.post_display == 1')
        ));

        $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
}

?>
```

And this guy would pass a variable called `posts` to my view, which would then render it accordingly. The thing is, isn't my model supposed to do anything else?, because if its as simple as this, there would be no point for custom models at all, I mean, its just an empty extension to the model class.

Comment: The simplest way to think of a model is the data storage and operations on that data that are agnostic to the interface (view).  In other words, pretend like your creating an API for your business problem with no specific knowledge of the interface.  The controller and view have knowledge of that ...

Comment: The `AppModel` instances have nothing to do with model layer of MVC. They are just instances of activerecord.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "empty extension to the model class" already does a lot of things: It hooks up to the database and does all the minute handling of retrieving and saving data. It *is supposed to* do a lot more though, including holding [validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation) which are enforced anytime you're writing to the database, any data massaging necessary in [before/after filters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1048/Callback-Methods) and any other custom *business logic* you need in your application. Models are for storing your central *business data logic*, so anything that's not presentation or input/output related but essentially models the core logic of your application. Just because the basics are simple to set up doesn't mean there isn't more to them.

Answer (score 4):

Models also encapsulate business logic and handle interactions with each other.  For example, if a Post has Comments, that's something that would be handled in the model.  You wouldn't want the controller to fetch the Post and then fetch the Comments and assemble them.  That would put the responsibility of knowing the model structure on the controller, where it doesn't belong.

There are, indeed, many applications where the models don't contain very much logic, if any at all.  A model with just data fields and no business logic can be thought of as a DTO (data transfer object) or just an "object" since it doesn't "model" any kind of business logic.  This isn't necessarily a bad thing, it depends on the needs.  Many application are simple forms-over-data apps and don't need any additional logic.

But if your application has more logic than just the data that's in any given table, that logic goes in the models.  They don't just model the data, they model the domain.  In fact, it's not uncommon for the models to not directly have the same structure of the database.  Models are object-oriented, whereas databases are much more commonly relational.  These two don't always solve problems in the same way.  If your models need to exactly copy your tables then you limit yourself from more object-oriented capabilities.

In short, anything that explains what the business does goes into the models.  The controllers are just event handlers, responding to user interface requests.  The controllers are generally customized for the application at hand, whereas models should be re-usable across multiple applications because they represent the core of the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

To use your example, the ideal is thin controllers and fat models. That means your code should ideally be refactored to the following:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';

    function retrieveLatest($limit = 10) {

        return $this->find('all', array(
            'order'=>'Post.id'=>'DESC',
            'limit'=>$limit
        );

    }

}


class PostsController extends AppController {

    function retrieve_latest($limit) {

      $posts = $this->Post->retrieveLatest($limit);

      $this->set(compact('posts'));

    }

}
```

Your controller shouldn't be concerned with the intricate details of what is neccessary to fetch the most recent, thats business logic and goes in the model, close to the data. Another benefit is you can also retrieve the latest posts from any related model:

```
$posts = $this->User->Post->retrieveLatest();
```

You could even go one stage further and move the retrieveLatest() code into your AppModel so every model would inherit it:

```
class AppModel extends Model {

    function retrieveLatest($limit = 10) {

        $model = $this->alias;

        return $this->find('all', array(
            'limit'=>$limit,
            'order'=>array(
                $model . ".id"=>'DESC'
            )
        );

    }    

}
```

As a rule of thumb, any time you find yourself building queries in your controllers, move them into the model and give them a descriptive name.